# How to add something in html string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How I can add something in html string with jquery.

String html :

```
var stringHtml = '<td>Column 1</td><td>Column 2</td><td></td>';
```

I want add something in last td ( td:eq(2) ), and then append it to table.

I try:-

```
var stringHtml = '<td>Column 1</td><td>Column 2</td><td></td>';

$(stringHtml).find('td:last').append('<button>MyButton</button>');

$('#myTable tbody').append(stringHtml);
```

This script not working.

Thank you for helping.

Comment: You should accept the answer rather than mentioning "Solved" see [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are appending the string, not the jQuery object.

```
var $ele = $('<td>Column 1</td><td>Column 2</td><td></td>');

$ele.find('td:last').append('<button>MyButton</button>');

$('#myTable tbody').append($ele);
// or $ele.appendTo('#myTable tbody');
```

---

**UPDATE :** The same behavior with one linear code using chaining.

```
$('<td>Column 1</td><td>Column 2</td><td></td>').appendTo('#myTable tbody').find('td:last').append('<button>MyButton</button>');
```